# getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList returns wrong result

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I'm trying to get enabled accessibility service list but the result returns wrong!

My service called ( Test App )

[getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager#getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(int)) returns 2 if the Test App was off. [The Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkszf.jpg)

But if I enabled Test App, It return 34. [The Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbDD3.jpg)

**Code**

```
public void isAccessibilityServiceEnabled() {
    AccessibilityManager accessibilityManager = (AccessibilityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    List < AccessibilityServiceInfo > accessibilityServiceInfoList = accessibilityManager.getEnabledAccessibilityServiceList(AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK);
    Log.w("ABCD", "" + accessibilityServiceInfoList.size()); //Returns 34!
}
```

Can I know why it returns 34?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
int accessibilityEnabled = 0;


Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS); 
accessibilityEnabled = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.Secure.ACCESSIBILITY_ENABLED);

if (accessibilityEnabled == 0) {
// accessibilityEnabled == 1 Enabled

startActivity(intent); //accessibility not enabled

}
```